# overloading dot "." with plus "+" in groovy dsl

Tags: groovy, dsl

how to overload the `.` operator with `+` operator in groovy. for example i have to build the DSL somethong like this:

`model+make+version` instead of `model.make.version`

how to build the dsl using `+` any example or hint

Comment: What if they want to add something in the DSL?

Comment: @tim_yates there is no add operation as in this question, but your point is valid, in this scenario every word is taken as string e.g:- model+make+version+"2"+... and many more

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload the `.`, you can overload a `+`. `model+make+version+"2"` actually evaluates to `model.plus(make.plus(version.plus("2")))`. Providing `plus` methods on those objects will do the trick, but the whole idea just seems ridiculous.